# Windows 7 Pro temporary profile loading

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-profiles

I have a Windows 7 Pro machine that I recently have set up. I joined the domain and when I attempt to login as a certain user, a temporary profile is loaded.

I have followed all of the typical steps for fixing a user profile (deleting all local versions of the profile, removing the users reg keys in profilelist, renaming the profile on the domain controller) yet the users profile will still not load. I logged in as another user on our domain and the profile loaded perfectly.

Are there any other reasons you may have encountered that could cause this issue? Are their any lesser known steps I need to take in order to make this profile work?

Any insight into what could be causing the problem would be helpful.

ERROR: ACCESS IS DENIED

EDIT (Below is the event viewer error):

Windows cannot locate the server copy of your roaming profile and is attempting to log you on with your local profile. Changes to the profile will not be copied to the server when you log off. This error my be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.

Log Name: Application

Source: User Profile Service

EventID: 1521

Level: Error

Comment: Please post an relevant info found in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Added them to the question.